# Score board assignment

Tags: php, forms, session, post

I need a app that counts the score, every time you press Verhogen. I tried it with sessions, but apparently the 2 sessions conflict with each other. Is there a way to fix this?

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_POST['thuisverhogen'])) {
    $_SESSION['thuisverhogen'] = 0;
} elseif (isset($_POST['thuisverhogen'])) {
    if (!($_SESSION['thuisverhogen'])) {
        $_SESSION['thuisverhogen'] = 1;
    } else {
        $thuisverhogen = $_SESSION['thuisverhogen'] + 1;
        $_SESSION['thuisverhogen'] = $thuisverhogen;
    }
}

if (!isset($_POST['uitverhogen'])) {
    $_SESSION['uitverhogen'] = 0;
} elseif (isset($_POST['uitverhogen'])) {
    if (!($_SESSION['uitverhogen'])) {
        $_SESSION['uitverhogen'] = 1;
    } else {
        $thuisverhogen = $_SESSION['uitverhogen'] + 1;
        $_SESSION['uitverhogen'] = $thuisverhogen;
    }
}
?>

<h2>SCORE</h2>
<form method="POST" action="2.php">
    Thuisscore: <input type="text" name="thuisscore" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['thuisverhogen'] ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="thuisverhogen" value="Verhogen"><br>

    Uitscore: <input type="text" name="uitscore" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['uitverhogen'] ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="uitverhogen" value="Verhogen">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to save the score locally in this browser session, or be able to access it later on in another session?

Comment: Just locally in the browser. I know I need to use multiple sessions, but how.

Comment: What I would do is do the counting with javascript instead of php, or does your application require php?

Comment: What is the output you are getting? Or at least, what is it doing now? By the way, what is your code in `2.php`?

Comment: It's outputting the values in the text fields. But every time I click on Verhogen, the other value in the text fields disappears. It only outputs one value in one text field, but I need both text fields because then you can compare the scores.

Comment: 2.php is just this file.

Comment: Your `$_POST` variable for the values of the scores are named `thuisscore` and `uitscore`, but you are not using these values in your php to add. You use the value of the button, which makes for the scores to influence each other. You could take a look at checking which variables to use at which point.

Comment: Is it possible to fix this problem with session_name?

Comment: Not sure, I am not proficient enough with `$_SESSION` to give you a good answer on that question. "Normally", you'd use javascript for client side handling of this type of behavior (like keeping a score) when you do not need to save it to a database for instance.

Comment: Why doesn't this work?                                                            $thuisscore = 0;
$uitscore = 0;
if (isset($_POST['thuisverhogen'])) {
    $thuisscore + 1;
}
if (isset($_POST['uiterhogen'])) {
    $uitscore + 1;
}
?>

<h2>SCORE</h2>
<form method="POST" action="2.php">
    Thuisscore: <input type="text" name="thuisscore" value="<?php echo $thuisscore ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="thuisverhogen" value="Verhogen"><br>

    Uitscore: <input type="text" name="uitscore" value="<?php echo $uitscore ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="uitverhogen" value="Verhogen">
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Found the answare

```
if (isset($_POST['thuisscore'])) {

    $thuisscore = $_POST['thuisscore'];
} else {
    $thuisscore = 0;
}

if (isset($_POST['uitscore'])) {
    $uitscore = $_POST['uitscore'];
} else {
    $uitscore = 0;
}

//verhogen
if (isset($_POST['thuisverhogen'])) {
    $thuisscore = $thuisscore + 1;
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['verhooguit'])) {
        $uitscore = $uitscore + 1;
    }
}
?>

<h2>SCORE</h2>
<form method="POST" action="2.php">
    Thuisscore: <input type="text" name="thuisscore" value="<?php echo $thuisscore ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="thuisverhogen" value="Verhogen"><br>

    Uitscore: <input type="text" name="uitscore" value="<?php echo $uitscore ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="verhooguit" value="Verhogen"><br>

</form>
```